# Click elsewhere not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('td').click(function() {
    if($('#edit').length == 0) {
      var idz = $(this).parent().attr('id');
      var textz = $(this).text();
      var rowz = $(this).attr('id');
      $(this).append('<textarea id=\"edit\" style=\"position:absolute;left:0;top:0;z-index:1;\">'+textz+'</textarea>').focus();
    }
  });
  if($('#edit').length > 0) {     
    $('html:not(#edit)').click(function() {
      $('#edit').remove();
    });
  }
});
</script>

    <div class="table">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Client</td>
            <td>Category</td>
            <td>Active</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="2">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Client 2</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="1">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Client 1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
       </table></div>
```

What I'm trying to do here is to intercept a click on *any* table cell and open a small textarea with the cell's value. *IT WORKS OKAY*.

But the peoblem is I'm trying to close the textarea by clicking elsewhere but not the #edit. So, this part of code doesn't work:

```
  if($('#edit').length > 0) {     
    $('html:not(#edit)').click(function() {
      $('#edit').remove();
    });
  }
```

I tried various ways of if/else statements, one if in another and so on and it still doesn't work. Please give me a hint of what's wrong with me.

Comment: Why add a click handler to every cell? Add just one `$(".table tbody").on("click", "td", function(){});`

Comment: @epascarello - does it really matter ?

Comment: @adeneo Looping through 10s, 100s, 1000s of cells adding an event or adding just one. You tell me...does it matter? ;)

Comment: No it doesn't? The looping only happens on pageload, the speed difference will not be noticeable until you have maybe a millions cells, and there's no difference when clicking the cell, if any, the delegated handler would be slower as it needs to filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#edit` element doesn't exist on first pageload, so the event handler is never bound as the condition fails.
Also, `html:not(#edit)` is usually not the way to go, attach the event handler to the document and check if the click originated from within `#edit`, if not remove `#edit`.

Change this

```
if($('#edit').length > 0) {     
    $('html:not(#edit)').click(function() {
        $('#edit').remove();
    });
}
```

to

```
$(document).on('mousedown', function(e) {
    if ( ! $(e.target).closest('#edit').length ) 
        $('#edit').remove();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/et93W/3/)

Comment: Yes it does. But if you edit the code in my question, it doesn't.

Comment: Oh, I see, it removes the #edit when clicking the TD as well. The only way around that is to filter out the TD's -> http://jsfiddle.net/et93W/1/

Comment: Well, actually there is, the mousedown event, changed the answer!